# Accessing UITabBarController from Appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to access my UiTabBarController from a UIViewController that is in UIWindow,

Since its not part on UITabBarController - using `self.tabBarController..` won't work as it will be nil.

So I tried this code:

```
BBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = appDelegate.window.rootViewController.tabBarController;
```

When it step through the code with the debugger - I can see `appDelegate` does have a tabBarController and it is not nil. However on the next line

```
  UITabBarController *tabBarController = appDelegate.window.rootViewController.tabBarController;
```

This results in `tabBarController` instance being nil and the `tabBarController` in the `appDelegate` still have a memory address assigned to it and its not nil.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**

Here is what my debugger looks like:

[image]
Thanks!

**Edit 2**

This is who I setup the side menu which is added to rootViewController

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone"
                                                         bundle: nil];

BBFilterViewController *loginController=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilterViewController"];  UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];



self.tabBarController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"HomeScreen"];

MVYSideMenuOptions *options = [[MVYSideMenuOptions alloc] init];
options.contentViewScale = 1.0;
options.contentViewOpacity = 0.5;
options.shadowOpacity = 0.0;

MVYSideMenuController *sideBarController = [[MVYSideMenuController alloc]initWithMenuViewController:navController contentViewController:self.tabBarController options:options];


self.window.rootViewController = sideBarController;

[self.window.rootViewController addChildViewController:self.tabBarController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: You need to describe your controller setup. Did you create your controllers (or some of them) in the app delegate, or are they made in the storyboard?

Comment: Only one controller is created in the app delegate. The rest are all in storyboard.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have tab bar controller as root view controller you can access it like:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
```

//Extended

Based on update to your question you should be able to get reference to tab bar controller from last child root view controller array:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController.childViewControllers.lastObject;
```

Comment: That's the whole problem. My rootViewController is not the tabbarController.

Comment: What is your view hierarchy?

Comment: In storyboard the tabBarController is the initial view controller. In app delegate I create a uivwcontroller and add it to the rootViewController

Comment: Can you post the code where you add uiviewcontroller to rootviewcontroller?

Comment: Please see extended post.

Answer (score -2):

From you debugger I think it should be `UITabBarController *tabBarController = appDelegate.tabBarController;`

Comment: appDelegate.tabBarController doesn't exist.